# Moving Traefik from Host Rule to Redirect Rules

Tags: docker, redirect, docker-compose, traefik

I have a *docker-compose.yml* that specifies a Traefik proxy service like so:

```
  proxy:
    container_name: traefik_proxy
    image: traefik:alpine
    command: >-
      --docker --logLevel=INFO \
      --acme \
      --acme.caserver="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" \
      --acme.acmelogging \
      --acme.dnschallenge=false \
      --acme.entrypoint="https" \
      --acme.httpchallenge \
      --acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint="http" \
      --acme.onhostrule=true \
      --acme.storage="/root/acme.json" \
      --acme.email="mark@bogus.net" \
      --entrypoints="Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https" \
      --entryPoints="Name:https Address::443 TLS TLS.MinVersion:VersionTLS12..." \ 
      --defaultentrypoints="http,https"
```

I deploy a new Docker container on my production host using something like this:

```
NAME=crb
HOST="crb.net"
IMAGE="summittdweller/crb"
docker container run -d --name ${NAME} \
    --label traefik.backend=${NAME} \
    --label traefik.docker.network=opt_webgateway \
    --label traefik.port=80 \
    --label "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${HOST}" \
    --label com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=true \
    --network opt_webgateway \
    --restart always \
    ${IMAGE}
```

With this deployment my site opens properly at *https://crb.net*.

I’m trying to craft Traefik rules for my deployment command so that the *crb.ne*t site will respond at any of three addresses…  *crb.net*, *thecrb.net*, or *thecrb.com*.  I’ve registered all three domains, but can’t come up with a set of Traefik rules that work.

I recently tried replacing the Host rule above with:

```
  HOST="crb.net|thecrb.net|thecrb.com"

  --label "traefik.frontend.redirect.regex=^https://(www.)?(${HOST})(.+)" \
  --label "traefik.frontend.redirect.replacement=https://crb.net$3" \
  --label "traefik.frontend.redirect.permanent=true" \
```

But I still get 404 errors on each domain.  Can anyone suggest a redirect, or other, rule set that might work?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you further describe "not work"? If you describe the behavior of the malfunction, it will help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes.  I've tried a number of different 'traefik.frontend.redirect' syntaxes and all of them end with 404 errors on all three domains.  I checked the Traefik logs but don't see any obvious errors.  I also tried varying the regex syntax and delimiters, even tested using one of the provided Go processors, and my first rule, namely `^http(s)://(www.)?(${HOST})(.+)` with replacement `https://crb.net$4`, passes the test but still returns all 404s.